# How to reduce a data frame keeping the order for other columns

Tags: r, dataframe, plyr, data.table

I am trying to reduce a data frame using the `max` function on a given column. I would like to preserve other columns but keeping the values from the same rows where each maximum value was selected. An example will make this explanation easier.

Let us assume we have the following data frame:

```
dframe <- data.frame(list(BENCH=sort(rep(letters[1:4], 4)),
                          CFG=rep(1:4, 4),
                          VALUE=runif(4 * 4)
                         ))
```

This gives me:

```
   BENCH CFG      VALUE
1      a   1 0.98828096
2      a   2 0.19630597
3      a   3 0.83539540
4      a   4 0.90988296
5      b   1 0.01191147
6      b   2 0.35164194
7      b   3 0.55094787
8      b   4 0.20744004
9      c   1 0.49864470
10     c   2 0.77845408
11     c   3 0.25278871
12     c   4 0.23440847
13     d   1 0.29795494
14     d   2 0.91766057
15     d   3 0.68044728
16     d   4 0.18448748
```

Now, I want to reduce the data in order to select the maximum VALUE for each different BENCH:

```
aggregate(VALUE ~ BENCH, dframe, FUN=max)
```

This gives me the expected result:

```
  BENCH     VALUE
1     a 0.9882810
2     b 0.5509479
3     c 0.7784541
4     d 0.9176606
```

Next, I tried to preserve other columns:

```
aggregate(cbind(VALUE, CFG) ~ BENCH, dframe, FUN=max)
```

This reduction returns:

```
  BENCH     VALUE CFG
1     a 0.9882810   4
2     b 0.5509479   4
3     c 0.7784541   4
4     d 0.9176606   4
```

Both VALUE and CFG are reduced using `max` function. But this is not what I want. For instance, in this example I would like to obtain:

```
  BENCH     VALUE CFG
1     a 0.9882810   1
2     b 0.5509479   3
3     c 0.7784541   2
4     d 0.9176606   2
```

where CFG is not reduced, but it just keeps the value associated to the maximum VALUE for each different BENCH.

How could I change my reduction in order to obtain the last result shown?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a base R solution:

```
do.call(rbind, by(dframe, dframe$BENCH, FUN=function(X) X[which.max(X$VALUE),]))
#   BENCH CFG     VALUE
# a     a   1 0.9882810
# b     b   3 0.5509479
# c     c   2 0.7784541
# d     d   2 0.9176606
```

Comment: It would sure be nice if `by()` had a `simplify`-like argument that would complete the split-apply-combine algorithm, putting the resultant data.frames back together. It comes so close ... and then makes you do the last step with that awkward `do.call(rbind, ...)` construct.

Comment: +1 for solving the question. Thank you! Actually, it does not look that bad in my opinion :)

Answer (score 5):

If your problem scales to large data (millions or 10s of millions of rows and groups), then package `data.table` may be of interest. Here's the relevant syntax:

```
require(data.table)
dtable <- data.table(dframe)
dtable[, .SD[which.max(VALUE),], by = BENCH]
```

Answer (score 1):

you could use `ddply` from the `plyr` package:

```
ddply(dframe, 
      .(BENCH), 
      function(df) return(df[df$VALUE==max(df$VALUE),]))
```

Comment: +1 for solving the question. Thank you! Just a minor thing, there is a missing parenthesis at the end.